# create nested array from ajax result

Tags: jquery

```js
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
dataType: 'jsonp',
url: 'https://wiljcr.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default/5158425934439969382?alt=json-in-script',
success: function(data) {
    var entry = data.entry;
    $(entry).each(function() {
        content = this.content.$t;
        myArray = {};
        $.each($(content), function() {
            var getClass = $(this).attr('class');
            myArray[getClass] = $(this).find("li").map(function() {
                return $(this).text();
            }).get()
        });
        console.log(myArray);
    });
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Current output, after countless trial n error:

```
{
    am: ["gud am", "good morning"],
    greetings: ["hi", "hello", "hey"]
}
```

Desired output:

```
[
    am = ["gud am", "good morning"],
    greetings = ["hi", "hello", "hey"]
]
```

Thanks for your help...

Comment: @freedomn-m `[
    am = ["gud am", "good morning"],
    greetings = ["hi", "hello", "hey"]
]` is not the output of that

Comment: @mplungjan yes, coming to that conclusion... `[ am = [` isn't a multi-dimensional array

Comment: @mplungjan Added an answer with some working snippets, but it won't give OPs exact requirement as, like you say, it's not quite js.

Comment: So `myArray=[];` using  `myArray.push($(this).find("li").map(function() {$(this).text()}).get())` is the closest you can come using array

Comment: @mplungjan, your solution works fine on my project, thanks! pls add it as an answer so i can select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest you can get would be

```
myArray=[];
myArray.push($(this).find("li").map(function() {$(this).text()}).get());
```